# how to install ruby offline?

Tags: installation, ruby, offline

I am trying to install ruby on a server which does not have connection to internet. I have copied ruby-1.9.2-p180.tar into ~/.rvm/archives. I tried to run rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p180 after that, but it still tries to download the file from the internet. How do I get this to install the tarfile which is inside the archives folder?
Any instruction for offline installation would be very helpful.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just install the `ruby1.9.1-full` package using an [offline installation method](http://askubuntu.com/q/974/667)?

Comment: its easier to maintain when you have multiple versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! There is a nice little tutorial on how to do offline rvm installation. 
http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/1d5dda17c41565bb